# How to position submit type input away from its form

Tags: html, css

I have the following type of form

```
    <form method="post" action="genTable.php" target="myIframe">

    <select id="leftValues" name="cols[ ]" size="5" multiple>
        <option>paper</option>
        <option>authors</option>
    </select>

    <div class="submitbutton">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Refresh Table" onclick="selectAll();">
    </div>

    </form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLrp3uL8/)

In that way the select form is always grouped together with the submit button. I want the button to be in a separate div with other buttons which is positioned separately from the form. However, if I separate them the button is not associated with the action of the form anymore. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the form an id:

```
<form id="MyForm" method="post" action="genTable.php" target="myIframe">

</form>
```

And then you can position your inputs anywhere on the page and just add the `form` attribute to attach them to the form:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Refresh Table" onclick="selectAll();" form="MyForm">
```

Note though, that this is not supported in Internet Explorer, but since you also have a `selectAll()` event handler, you can also submit the form through JavaScript:

```
function selectAll()
{
  // submit the form
  document.getElementById('MyForm').submit();

  // Prevent the default submit in non-IE browsers, otherwise you'll have two submits.
  return false;
}
```

This way, it will work everywhere, except in IE browsers where JavaScript is disables. That audience is probably small enough to be acceptable.